Detectron 2 - Problem in instance segmentation
I followed the steps of a tutorial for instance segmentation using Detectron 2  with my own dataset (the annotations were created with ImageJ but were succesfully converted to COCO format with a python script). I have 108 training images with only 1 class (multiple instances of this class in each image).
When I visualize some random annotated samples before training, everything seems correct and every instance is drawn with the correct shape. In addition, a bounding box is drawn for each instance.
Nevertheless, after training, when doing inference, only bounding boxes appear on random validation images or test images.
Looking at the metrics, object detection has a low percentaje, but evaluation results for segmentation are even worse bacause the AP is 0, so it seems that there is an error I cannot find. How could I solve it?
*Bounding boxes cross each other, Idk if this is the problem

Videotutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEgF0YknpZw&ab_channel=DigitalSreeni
Code: https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/330_Detectron2_Instance_3D_EM_Platelet.ipynb
